Next JS app router importing static image problem
I'm currently using the app router in Next.JS. When importing images from the public server using the one below from a reusable component
<img src="assets/icon.png" />

It will import as normal from the index root page and a folder above it. But I noticed when I created a second folder inside a folder above the root that it doesn't import the images no longer.
Now, it says error that it can't find the image no longer but I found that when the page does move up 2 routes that it adds the first route into the import.
So lets say I got this folder structure

app
item
[slug]

it will add the item into the import string for some reason like this when I use the component in the slug page as the error would report. Even though the src is normal in the import when I hover over it it says this.
http://localhost:3000/tester/assets/icon.png

instead of
http://localhost:3000/assets/icon.png

Is there any way to stop this from happening in my reusable component?
I've tried changing the import with "./" at the beginning or a "/" and it did not work. Next will automatically add the folder below when importing the images from the reusable component.
